# How to create a responsive webpage using jqwidget?

Tags: jqwidget

I am using jqwidget for creating a webpage. But the page is not responsive. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find demos on jQWidgets website like this: http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/twitter/index.htm which shows how to use Bootstrap with jQWidgets and also http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jquerymobile/index.htm#demos/jquerymobile/jquerymobile.htm which shows how to use jQuery Mobile with jQWidgets.

Hope this helps.